# installation of ridgerun sdk - Leopard board DM

Tags: linux, opencv, sdk

I want to install ridgerun sdk to build and run applications on Leopardboard DM365. I am new to this and I have followed steps as per ridgerun sdk getting started guide - https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/DM365_Leopard_SDK_2011Q2_Getting_Started_Guide

I have installed the sdk as per the guide. Then as per the guide I configure the sdk to build it - "make configure". In the configuration I selected support for opencv-2.1.0. Then when I "make" the sdk, I get the following error:

```
Checking dependencies for OpenCV-2.1.0
Compiling and installing OpenCV-2.1.0...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
CMake Warning: The variable, 'BUILD_DOXYGEN_DOCS', specified manually, was not used during the generation.
CMake Warning: The variable, 'BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT', specified manually, was not used during the generation.
CMake Warning: The variable, 'CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE', specified manually, was not used during the generation.
make[3]: *** [cmake_built] Error 2
Error building OpenCV-2.1.0
make[2]: *** [dependency_build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps_build] Error 1
make: *** [fs_build] Error 2
```

I am stuck up at this point. I searched a lot but cannot find anything. Please guide me as to what has to be done.
Thanks,
Maz

Answer (score 2):

You must disable OpenCV and compile again.

Goto the root directory of your RRSDK and run:

```
make config
```

goto "**File System Configuration  --->Select target's file system software**"

Deselect "OpenCV".

Exit and run:

```
make
make install
```

OpenCV is known to have a bug in configuration in this version of RRSDK.